# How can I combine these two tables so that I can sort with information on each table, but not get duplicate answers?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables. The first is named `master_list`. It has these fields: `master_id`, `item_id`, `name`, `img`, `item_code`, and `length`. My second table is named `types_join`. It has these fields: `master_id` and `type_id`. (There is a third table, but it is not being used in the queries. It is more for reference.) I need to be able to combine these two tables so that I can sift the results to only show certain ones but part of the information to sift is on one table and the other part is on the other one. I don't want duplicate answers.

For example say I only want items that have a type_id of 3 and a length of 18.

When I use

```
SELECT * FROM master_list LEFT JOIN types_join ON master_list.master_id=types_join.master_id WHERE types_join.type_id = 3 AND master_list.length = 18"
```

it finds the same thing twice.

How can I query this so I won't get duplicate answers?

Here are the samples from my tables and the result I am getting.

[image]

This is what I get with an INNER JOIN:

[image]

BTW, `master_id` and `name` both only have unique information on the `master_list` table. However, the `types_join` table does use the master_id multiple times later on, but not for Lye. That is why I know it is duplicating information.

Comment: You didn't show any data, but i am guessing, that your master_list.master_id=types_join.master_id hits more than once. Ajoin would combine every match that it finds. Your left join even adds all rows that haven't a match. You should see if you can group them together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want unique rows from `master_list`, use `exists`:

```
SELECT ml.*
FROM master_list ml
WHERE ml.length = 18 AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM types_join tj
              WHERE ml.master_id = tj.master_id AND tj.type_id = 3 
             );
```

Any duplicates you get will be duplicates in `master_list`.  If you want to remove them, you need to provide more information -- I would recommend a new question.

Comment: If master list items is all that he needs, he could simple do the join and use distinct

Comment: First, he is actually a she in this case. Second, yes, I really only need the master list information, but need the join for sorting purposes. I originally had them all in one list with the type_id included, but now have a section that has multiple type_id's for the same master_id.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff, that seems to work like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff, would you be willing to chat with me to help me fix this stuff? This fixed some of my issues, but I have at least one page that is slightly more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the data. But as you can see [enter link description here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wLwTuADaF7aMQwiEXyvnjC/1), there is nothing wrong with your query.

Have you tried create an unique index over master_id, just to make sure that you do not have duplicated rows?

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX MyMasterUnique
ON master_list(master_id);
```

Comment: To clear up the duplicates issue, the query I posted normally would have brought up Lye, but it is putting up Lye twice.

Comment: However, this query still has the same issue mine has. It is pulling up the same line twice.

Comment: As you provided no data sample, I'm assuming that Lye is the name one master_list item. How many rows do you have on master_list with Lye? Better yet, can you provide some sample data?

Comment: I added some sample information to my original question to help.

Comment: 'master_id' is actually the primary on 'master_list'.

Comment: Hi Hevnlymom First of all I'm sorry I took you for a "dude" and second I'm glad you have found the solution to your problem with the reponse from @Gordon. Never the less, I think that the solution using the EXISTS subquery is probably hiding duplicate values if not on the master_list table, on the types_join, the same would occur if you use the DISTINCT. I would recommend to ensure that no duplicated record exists on any of the table that you are using on the joins, and than tackle the remaining issues.

Comment: Actually, I am using the distinct on many of my pages, but that one page was giving issues for some reason. As for duplicates in my tables, I used both unique and primary (creates unique as well) to make sure I don't have duplicates in the tables.